# initializing a vector with a lambda being fed the index in c++

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a library function for initializing a vector based on the index of its elements ?

This would shorten things like :

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  auto square = [] (int n) {return n*n;};

  vector<int> v(5, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    v[i] = square(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a vector there is easy way to calculate its index by subtracing pointers:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(), 
    [&v,&square](auto& elem){ elem = square(&elem - &v[0]);});
```

by `auto& elem` you access original item of vector then index is calculated by `&elem - &v[0]` which is passed into `square`.

Answer (score 4):

The way that comes to mind is to break it into two steps. In this case [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) will fill the vector with the inputs (0, 1, 2, etc). Then [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) will perform your function `square` on each of the elements and replace them in the vector.

```
int main()
{
    auto square = [] (int n) {return n*n;};

    std::vector<int> v(5, 0);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), square);

    for (int i : v)
      std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

[Output](http://cpp.sh/95for)

```
0 1 4 9 16
```

Honestly this is the kind of thing that will be much more concise and streamlined once [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) are available, [C++20 working example](https://godbolt.org/z/RHh_S-)

```
int main()
{
    auto square = [] (int n) {return n*n;};

    for (int i : std::views::iota(0, 5) | std::views::transform(square))
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```